# Запись в базу Elasticsearch через PHP (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

Мне нужно записывать в базу такие поля как `id`, `accessToken`, `refreshToken`. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать средствами Symfony.

Entity:

```
<?php
namespace App\Portmone\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Search\Mapping\Annotations as MAP;

/***@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TransactionEntityRepository")
* @MAP\ElasticSearchable(index="portmone", type="transaction", source=true)
*/
class TransactionEntity
{
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @MAP\ElasticField(type="integer", includeInAll=true)
 */
private $id;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @MAP\ElasticField(type="integer", includeInAll=true, boost=5.0)
 */
private $sourceCardId;

public function getSourceCardId()
{
    return $this->sourceCardId;
}
public function setSourceCardId(int $sourceCardId)
{
    $this->sourceCardId = $sourceCardId;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @MAP\ElasticField(type="integer", includeInAll=true, boost=5.0)
 */
private $destinationCardId;

public function getDestinationCardId()
{
    return $this->sourceCardId;
}
public function setDestinationCardId(int $destinationCardId)
{
    $this->destinationCardId = $destinationCardId;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 * @MAP\ElasticField(type="float", includeInAll=true, boost=5.0)
 */
private $transferredMoney;

public function getTransferredMoney(): ?float
{
    return $this->transferredMoney;
}

public function setTransferredMoney(float $transferredMoney): self
{
    $this->transferredMoney = $transferredMoney;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @MAP\ElasticField(type="date", includeInAll=true, boost=5.0)
 */
private $transactionDate;

public function getTransactionDate()
{
    return $this->transactionDate;
}

public function setTransactionDate($transactionDate)
{
    $this->transactionDate = $transactionDate;
    return $this;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым делам необходимо создать соответствующий маппинг в ES. Тут, наверное, останавливаться нет смысла. В документации много примеров.

Далее Симфони:

composer.json:

```
...
"require": {
    ...
    "ruflin/elastica": "dev-master"
    ...
},
```

config/services.yaml

```
parameters:
    elastic:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 9200

services:
    Elastica\Client:
        arguments:
            - '%elastic%'

    App\Controller\HomeController:
        arguments:
            - '@Elastica\Client'
        public: true
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Elastica\Client;
use Elastica\Document;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Class HomeController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class HomeController
{
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * HomeController constructor.
     *
     * @param Client $client
     */
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(): Response
    {
        $document = new Document('1', [
            'id' => 1,
            'accessToken' => 'accessTokenValue',
            'refreshToken' => 'refreshTokenValue',
        ], '_doc');

        $res = $this->client->getIndex('test')->addDocuments([$document]);

        return Response::create($res);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function queryAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        $query = new \Elastica\Query($request->query->get('query'));
        $res = $this->client->getIndex('test')->search($query);
        $ress = $res->getResponse()->getData();
        return Response::create(json_encode($ress));
    }
}
```

Вы должны понимать, что это простой пример, возможно, вы в своей структуре организуете модели и прочее.

Comment: а как записывать через Entity?

Comment: Как генерировать id документа автоматом по порядку от 1 до ...?

Comment: @RevOiT конечно можно, я привел пример "по-быстрому", а если разобраться, [это решение](https://github.com/doctrine/search#mappings), может оказаться, вам полезным.

Comment: Спасибо.
Не подскажешь почему показывает такую ошибку "No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "?

Comment: для этого мне надо видеть, что у тебя с энтити)

Comment: добавил энтити выше

Comment: Честно говоря, сложно сказать, попробуй до `@ORM\Id`,  добавить `@ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")`, если не поможет, сделай репу на гитхабе, попробую помочь, в свободное время

Comment: У меня основная БД в Postgres, а TransactionEntity в Elastic. Должна ли создаватся таблица TransactionEntity в Postgres?

Comment: Тут два пути: 1) Много данных в постргресе и чтобы не нагружать ее поиском, используется эластик, для получения айдишников строк 2) использовать эластик как самостоятельное хранилище БД. А если вопрос касаемо ОРМ, то нет, не должна